# How to handle wrong PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have endpoint :

```
@GetMapping("/student/{id})
public Student getStudentByID(@PathVariable Long id)
```

How to handle the situation: `/student/aaa`
When the user passes something else than `Long`. Now I have received 400 Bad Request and Empty JSON for the above request.

Comment: 400 sounds like a good response. What you want is customizing the response? If so, please specify that in your question, e.g. "I would like to respond with a specific 4xx code. How could I handle this?"

Comment: I would like to response with a 400 code and message "ID must be a number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

400 Status code is a good response as per your coding.

See the below examples:

Below api will accept the integer. example `student/123`.

```
@GetMapping("/student/{id}")
public Student getStudentByID(@PathVariable Long id)
```

Below api will accept the string. example `/student/aaa`

```
@GetMapping("/student/{id}")
public Student getStudentByID(@PathVariable String id)
```

If you want add validation use the below code:

```
    @GetMapping("/student/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Student> getStudentByID(@PathVariable String id) {
       try {
          Long id = Long.valueOf(id);
       } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
      }
      return ResponseEntity.ok(new Student());
    }
```

Small Advice, always use the, **ResponseEntity** in your services. So you can control/return the status code. Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Answer (score 1):

To control your error handling, you can accept String parameter and catch Exception if failed to convert to long

```
public Student getStudentByID(@PathVariable String idString) {
    try {
        Long id = Long.valueOf(idString);

   } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        // handle non long value
   }
```